# What is the loud clanking sound at low RPM (video included)

Tags: diesel, noise

At low RPM, which occurs in 3 different scenarios (starting, shut down, and clutch-out), the noise I am hearing comes from the engine compartment.

The van in question is a 2003 Kia Pregio diesel van. Here's a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhQ9Z10VYTM&feature=youtu.be

In the video you can hear the sound in question right after attempts to start. This sound disappears during idle and in normal driving conditions, but re-appears whenever I let the clutch out enough that the RPMs dip below idle, and it also happens when I shut the car down.

In case you are wondering, there is also a problem with the engine starter-circuit which is cause for multiple attempts to start in the video--I'm still working on diagnosing this one, which I have posted a question for, here: [2003 Kia Pregio Diesel Van: engine starter problem (video included)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/35355/2003-kia-pregio-diesel-van-engine-starter-problem-video-included/35697#35697)

I don't really know what this is - maybe knocking from timing being off? Please help :)

Comment: Maybe it is a bad motor mount, it sound like the engine/tranny is hitting something

Answer (score 1):

Your having trouble starting and once it starts you get a short period of clacking sounds.
It sounds like a possible issue with the starter pinion gear not engaging and disengaging fully.   This could be the solenoid, guide sleeve or driven shaft for the pinion gear.
Pull starter and have it tested or test it yourself.  Pay attention to see if the pinion gear snaps sharply in when starter engaged and snaps quickly back when disengaged.

Comment: It also happens at just low RPM in driving, could this be the same thing?

Comment: I have seen solenoids go bad in several ways.  One is the return spring corroding which weakens it this keep the pinion gear from fully retracting and it has enough play to bounce.   Also have seen the plastic sleeve that lines some starter solenoids wear allowing things to bind intermittently.   testing it outside the car to see operation is consistent and reliable and/or pull the solenoid off and visually inspect.   Not sure on your Kia how hard it is to pull but if it is easy enough will eliminate one item from the list of possibles.